# SymPy doit returns NaN instead of zero

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to evaluate a long expression with lots of summations and n choose k's. For some reason, the following expression (which is a part of the long expression) returns NaN.

```
from sympy import *
w_1_2_3 = symbols('w_1_2_3')
w_1_3 = symbols('w_1_3')
w_2_3 = symbols('w_2_3')
w_1_2 = symbols('w_1_2')
exprr = 7*Sum(binomial(5, w_1_2_3)*Sum(binomial(0, -w_1_2_3 + w_1_3)*binomial(2, w_1_2_3 - w_1_3 - 2)*binomial(13, 11 - w_1_2_3), (w_1_3, w_1_2_3, 5)), (w_1_2_3, 0, 5))/868017280
exprr.doit()
-> NaN
```

However, if I evaluate each of the terms in the first sum separately, I get 0 for each of them (as should be):

```
exprr2 = binomial(5, w_1_2_3)*Sum(binomial(0, -w_1_2_3 + w_1_3)*binomial(2, w_1_2_3 - w_1_3 - 2)*binomial(13, 11 - w_1_2_3), (w_1_3, w_1_2_3, 5))

for t in range(0, 6):
    res = exprr2.subs(w_1_2_3, t).doit()
    print(t, res)
-> 0 0
   1 0
   2 0
   3 0
   4 0
   5 0
```

What is going on here? Why do I get NaN for the overall term?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your example a little to wrap my head around it:

```py
from sympy import *

a = symbols("a", integer=True)
b = symbols("b", integer=True)
summand = binomial(5, a) * Sum(
    binomial(0, -a + b)
    * binomial(2, a - b - 2)
    * binomial(13, 11 - a),
    (b, a, 5),
)
inner_sum = summand.doit()#.simplify()   # <--- the important part
summation = (
    7
    * Sum(
        inner_sum,
        (a, 0, 5),
    )
    / 868017280
)
print(summation.doit())


for t in range(0, 6):
    res = summand.subs(a, t).doit()
    print(t, res)
```

Note how I told sympy to do the inner sum explicitly via `.doit()`. Let's take a look at that:

```
>>> pprint(inner_sum)
        ⎛   4        3        2               ⎞ ⎛  0  ⎞ ⎛  2  ⎞ ⎛5⎞ ⎛  13  ⎞
(a - 5)⋅⎝6⋅a  - 102⋅a  + 607⋅a  - 1407⋅a + 756⎠⋅⎜     ⎟⋅⎜     ⎟⋅⎜ ⎟⋅⎜      ⎟
                                                ⎝5 - a⎠ ⎝a - 7⎠ ⎝a⎠ ⎝11 - a⎠
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     a⋅(a - 6)⋅(a - 3)⋅(a - 2)⋅(a - 1)
```

Note how the denominator is chock-full of zeros just at the numbers you're summing this whole thing over! This is in fact what's causing the `nan`s to appear when you sum them.

If, instead, we massage this thing a little, your binomials disappear and merge with the zeros from the denominator, becoming factorials in the denominator, which are safe to work with:

```
>>> pprint(inner_sum.simplify().factor())
               ⎛   4        3        2               ⎞
-1494484992000⋅⎝6⋅a  - 102⋅a  + 607⋅a  - 1407⋅a + 756⎠
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
        2
(-a)!⋅a! ⋅(3 - a)!⋅(9 - a)!⋅(11 - a)!⋅(a - 1)!⋅(a + 2)!
```

And this expression sums properly over the [0, 6] range, as you can verify.